# Can I compare the source window from postMessage to my window.frames?

Tags: javascript, html, xss, postmessage

I want to bubble some information from a frame to its parent object (information that isn't accessible due to XSS).

Can I compare the `source` window sent via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to the values of `window.frames`?

MDN (in the link above) says that the message can be used to `postMessage` back but doesn't refer to testing for equality.

This works correctly on IE9 FF5 and Chrome12 but I want to know if this is dependable (i.e. is it in the standard).

Test code:

**postMessageOuter.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Outer Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i)
                if (event.source == frames[i])
                    alert(i);
        }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="postMessageInner.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="postMessageInner.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="postMessageInner.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**postMessageInner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inner Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo() {
            window.parent.postMessage("Hello", "*");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="X" onclick="foo()" />    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postMessage` is part of the `HTML5` draft and thus supported in the newest browsers.

The spec says

> the source attribute must be set to the script's global object's WindowProxy object

this WindowProxy is the value of the window.frame enumeration, too.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#crossDocumentMessages